# Postman request with 'global' URL

Tags: url, request, postman

I want to know if it's possible to add a "prefix" to all request URLs in Postman?

Normally a request looks like this:

[HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrBjD.png)

```
http://localhost:8000/test
```

But I want to just put:

```
/test
```

And put the `http://localhost:8000` like a global URL.

I ask this because I swap so much from local to server for same URL and I would like to just change one URL and not URLs for all requests all the time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you looked at using an `environment` file?

https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/environments_and_globals/manage_environments

Add a variable called `url` with the `http://localhost:8000` value. You can then use this value in the URL like `{{url}}`.

If your requests are constructed like `{{url}}/test` - You can create as many environments as you like with the `url` variable different in each one. So by changing the `environment` this will point your requests at a local, staging or production server.